# How to print multiple json values with same fields in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print json values in python like below from the json output I receive from the API.

POSTCODE : CB3 0FA
COUNTRY  : England
REGION   : East of England

POSTCODE : CB3 0GT
COUNTRY  : England
REGION   : East of England

POSTCODE : CB3 0FT
COUNTRY  : England
REGION   : East of England

```
def loadJsonResponse(url):
    return json.loads(req.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8'))['result']


def nearestPostcode(postcode):
    url = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/{}/nearest'.format(postcode)
    value = loadJsonResponse(url)
    for i in value['result']:
        zip_code = i['postcode']
        print (zip_code)
```

Below is my Json output:

```
{
"status": 200,
"result": [
    {
        "postcode": "CB3 0FA",
        "quality": 1,
        "eastings": 542934,
        "northings": 258794,
        "country": "England",
        "nhs_ha": "East of England",
        "longitude": 0.090435,
        "latitude": 52.208837,
        "european_electoral_region": "Eastern",
        "primary_care_trust": "Cambridgeshire",
        "region": "East of England",
        "lsoa": "Cambridge 007D",
        "msoa": "Cambridge 007",
        "incode": "0FA",
        "outcode": "CB3",
        "distance": 0,
        "parliamentary_constituency": "Cambridge",
        "admin_district": "Cambridge",
        "parish": "Cambridge, unparished area",
        "admin_county": "Cambridgeshire",
        "admin_ward": "Newnham",
        "ccg": "NHS Cambridgeshire and Peterborough",
        "nuts": "Cambridgeshire CC",
        "codes": {
            "admin_district": "E07000008",
            "admin_county": "E10000003",
            "admin_ward": "E05002710",
            "parish": "E43000042",
            "parliamentary_constituency": "E14000617",
            "ccg": "E38000026",
            "nuts": "UKH12"
        }
    },
    {
        "postcode": "CB3 0GT",
        "quality": 1,
        "eastings": 542895,
        "northings": 258788,
        "country": "England",
        "nhs_ha": "East of England",
        "longitude": 0.089862,
        "latitude": 52.208793,
        "european_electoral_region": "Eastern",
        "primary_care_trust": "Cambridgeshire",
        "region": "East of England",
        "lsoa": "Cambridge 007D",
        "msoa": "Cambridge 007",
        "incode": "0GT",
        "outcode": "CB3",
        "distance": 39.47393492,
        "parliamentary_constituency": "Cambridge",
        "admin_district": "Cambridge",
        "parish": "Cambridge, unparished area",
        "admin_county": "Cambridgeshire",
        "admin_ward": "Newnham",
        "ccg": "NHS Cambridgeshire and Peterborough",
        "nuts": "Cambridgeshire CC",
        "codes": {
            "admin_district": "E07000008",
            "admin_county": "E10000003",
            "admin_ward": "E05002710",
            "parish": "E43000042",
            "parliamentary_constituency": "E14000617",
            "ccg": "E38000026",
            "nuts": "UKH12"
        }
    },
    {
        "postcode": "CB3 0FT",
        "quality": 1,
        "eastings": 542856,
        "northings": 258824,
        "country": "England",
        "nhs_ha": "East of England",
        "longitude": 0.089307,
        "latitude": 52.209126,
        "european_electoral_region": "Eastern",
        "primary_care_trust": "Cambridgeshire",
        "region": "East of England",
        "lsoa": "Cambridge 007D",
        "msoa": "Cambridge 007",
        "incode": "0FT",
        "outcode": "CB3",
        "distance": 83.54443275,
        "parliamentary_constituency": "Cambridge",
        "admin_district": "Cambridge",
        "parish": "Cambridge, unparished area",
        "admin_county": "Cambridgeshire",
        "admin_ward": "Newnham",
        "ccg": "NHS Cambridgeshire and Peterborough",
        "nuts": "Cambridgeshire CC",
        "codes": {
            "admin_district": "E07000008",
            "admin_county": "E10000003",
            "admin_ward": "E05002710",
            "parish": "E43000042",
            "parliamentary_constituency": "E14000617",
            "ccg": "E38000026",
            "nuts": "UKH12"
        }
    }
]
}
```

I see below error on execution of the script.

```
Enter the postcode : CB3 0FA
You entered postcode--> CB3 0FA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./py_script3.py", line 62, in <module>
    nearestPostcode(postcode)
  File "./py_script3.py", line 42, in nearestPostcode
    for i in value['result']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Please explain what is the problem here.

Comment: I added the error in main question at the end.. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, using formatted print, tested by loading your `json` output

```
for i in value['result']:
    print('POSTCODE: {} England REGION: {}'.format(i['postcode'], i['region']))

POSTCODE: CB3 0FA England REGION: East of England
POSTCODE: CB3 0GT England REGION: East of England
POSTCODE: CB3 0FT England REGION: East of England
```

Comment: Enter the postcode : CB3 0FA
You entered postcode--> CB3 0FA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./py_script3.py", line 62, in <module>
    nearestPostcode(postcode)
  File "./py_script3.py", line 42, in nearestPostcode
    for i in value['result']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I added in the main question, my apologies

Comment: @garg_hbti I want to say the issue is how you are loading the json, can you fix the indentation on your post and  show how you are calling nearest postcode

Comment: @garg_hbti if you save that file into a `blah.json` and then load it, it works so it has to be something with how you are loading it, not the actual looping of the contents

Comment: The miss was ,I was returning the result section directly from the loadJsonResponse(url), once I removed the ['result'] section from there it worked like a charm. Thanks!!

Comment: @garg_hbti awesome! glad it worked out :) thats makes sense now, good eye!